# Save Worksheets to new Workbook By Checkbox [Excel Macro/VBA]

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, macros

So my main goal is to save sheets (depending on if they are selected by a checkbox) to a new workbook.

Here is my code:

```
Sub saveSheetWorkbook()

Dim exampleName As Variant
Dim exampleSavePath As String
Dim exampleSheet As Variant

exampleName = InputBox("Who will this be sent to?")

exampleSavePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & exampleName

If Worksheets("Example Worksheet 1").Range("E29") = True Then
exampleSheet = "Example Worksheet 2"
End If

Sheets(Array("Example Worksheet 1"), exampleSheet).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=exampleSavePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

For example, I want to always save Example Worksheet 1, but only save Example Worksheet 2 if the checkbox is ticked. The cell E29 in Example Worksheet 1 is the linked cell for the checkbox.

So this macro works when the checkbox is ticked, but when the checkbox is unticked, I get an error.

I have set it up so that the sheet array either contains the name or nothing. but when containing nothing, that gives me the error.

Any help would be great.

Edit: I need this for 6 different checkboxes/sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have one parenthesis too much

then

```
Sub saveSheetWorkbook()

    Dim exampleName As Variant
    Dim exampleSavePath As String
    Dim sheetsArray As Variant

    exampleName = InputBox("Who will this be sent to?")

    exampleSavePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & exampleName

    If Worksheets("Example Worksheet 1").Range("E29") Then
        sheetsArray = Array("Example Worksheet 1", "Example Worksheet 2")
    Else
        sheetsArray = Array("Example Worksheet 1")
    End If

    Sheets(sheetsArray).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=exampleSavePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh yes sorry I forgot to mention that I have more than 1 checkbox. I have a list of 6 checkboxes. I could make 64 if statements but that wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: well this is a completely new matter. as per this site rules 1) every question is to be closed as per its _original_ issues. So if my answer solved your _original_ question please mark it as accepted  2) new issues must be posted with a new question

Comment: in the new question you'd better both give as much detail as possible and show your coding efforts along with problems it arouse, very much like you did in this question

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it was a big issue as you only slightly adjusted my IF statement. I will remember for next time.

Comment: I don't get you: didn't my answer solve your question?

Comment: Well your answer isn't practical for multiple checkboxes unfortunately sorry.

Comment: I see, but when I gave my answer there was not any multiple checkboxes issue around

Answer (score 0):

You can use my example workbook to do this with form:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzFv0oeets6ubHg2bk96SHotdkU

To create this by yourself, here is instructions:

1. Press ALT+F11 in order to open VBA window;
2. Create userform with name **"Userform1"**
3. Put listbox to form and change its name to **"lstSheet"**
4. Change its properties like shown below:

   - **ListStyle:** 1-fmListStyleOPtion;
   - **MultiSelect:** 1-fmMultiSelectMulti;

Userform code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim NewName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim NumSheets As Integer


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Count As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Count = 0
For i = 0 To lstSheet.ListCount - 1
    'check if the row is selected and add to count
    If lstSheet.Selected(i) Then Count = Count + 1
Next i
For i = 0 To lstSheet.ListCount - 1
    If lstSheet.Selected(i) Then Sheets(lstSheet.List(i)).Select True

Next i


For i = 0 To lstSheet.ListCount - 1
If lstSheet.Selected(i) Then Sheets(lstSheet.List(i)).Select False
If lstSheet.Selected(i) Then Sheets(lstSheet.List(i)).Activate
Next i
Unload Me
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Cells.Copy
            ws.[A1].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            ws.Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Cells(1, 1).Select
            ws.Activate
        Next ws
        Cells(1, 1).Select

         '       Remove named ranges

         '       Input box to name new file
        NewName = InputBox("Please Specify the name of your new workbook", "New Copy")

         '       Save it with the NewName and in the same directory as original
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & NewName & ".xlsx"

        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub lstSheet_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Sh As Variant
    'for each loop the add visible sheets
    For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        'only visible sheetand exclude login sheet
        If Sh.Visible = True Then
            'add sheets to the listbox
            Me.lstSheet.AddItem Sh.Name
        End If
    Next Sh
End Sub
```

5. Create Module and put this code there:

```
 
Sub showForm()
  Userform1.Show
End Sub
```